# How can I Write text to a PDF within a boundary? - Python

Tags: python, pdf, text

I have various sized `txt files` I want to put into a `PDF`, is there any way I can describe an area `(x1,y1,x2,y2)` for the text to fill in. This would need to be flow-able. And if it could rescale to be as big of text as possible while still fitting that would be a nice bonus, Thank you for any help

With in the PIL Library you can use `pdf.image(picture,x,y,x2,y2)` to place the image, this can scale/crop the image.

```
import reportlab

pdf = canvas.Canvas("myfile.pdf")

pdf.drawString(10,800, someText) //This is the current way, But ideally I would like

pdf.drawBoxString(10,800, 400, 1000, someText)
```

If this doesn't work should I try to nest another canvas inside of it

Comment: Did you get the answer as I am also looking for the same? I am getting bounded box containing text from ocr. I need to convert it to pdf.

Comment: Not yet :( I strayed away from pdf's to find another way